# What to prefer a llvm::StringMap or std::map during code generation using llvm

Tags: c++, llvm

I am currently working on a project where I have to keep track of different variables using a symbol table. Similar to the kaleidoscope 
[tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial) presented on the LLVM homepage.

In the example code, they use an std::map to achieve this functionality.

```
static std::map<std::string, AllocaInst*> NamedValues;
```

In a practical scenario similar to the tutorial would a 
[llvm::StringMap](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1StringMap.html#a987049afc1d158e62e8b824533b7d367)

```
llvm::StringMap< ValueTy, AllocatorTy >
```

be prefereed over the std::map approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, but I don't really see a reason why llvm::StringMap would be strictly preferred over std::map. Based [on these slides](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2014-04/PDFs/LightningTalks/data_structure_llvm.pdf) (slides 23,24) it seems that llvm::StringMap is slower than std::map and std::unordered_map  for both inserts and lookups.

Additionally, as explained [here](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html):

> StringMap iteration order, however, is not guaranteed to be deterministic, so any uses which require that should instead use a std::map.

So, keep that in mind in case you end up using llvm::StringMap instead of std::map.